Volume of shifted and modified cylinder using polar coordinates
I have a shifted and modified cylinder $x^2+y^2=4x$, bounded below by $z=0$ and above by $z=\sqrt{16-x^2-y^2}$. I want to find its volume. Completing the square and conversion to polar coordinates give $x^2+y^2=4x \Rightarrow r(r-4\cos \theta)$. My problem is, if I integrate over $-\pi/2\leq \theta \leq \pi/2$, I get
\begin{align}
V = \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \int_0^{4\cos\theta}\sqrt{16-r^2}r \ dr\ d\theta = \frac{64\pi}{3}
\end{align}
as my answer. However, if I integrate over $0 \leq \theta \leq \pi/2$ and multiply by 2 (for the outer integral), I get
\begin{align}
V = 2\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \int_0^{4\cos\theta}\sqrt{16-r^2}r \ dr\ d\theta = \frac{64\pi}{3} - \frac{256}{9}.
\end{align}
as my answer. Integrating the integrand with respect to $r$ gives $-\frac{1}{3}(16-r^2)^{3/2}$. Thus, the inner integral becomes $\frac{64}{3}(1-\sin^3\theta)$. Plotting this with with $\theta$ for x-axis gives

Which integration actually gives the correct answer?

The latter volume is the correct one.
Take a closer look at the $r$-integral:
$$\begin{align*}
\int_0^{4\cos\theta} r \sqrt{16 - r^2} \, dr &= 64 \int_0^{\cos\theta} r \sqrt{1 - r^2} \, dr \\
&= -32 \int_0^{\cos\theta} \sqrt{1-r^2} \, d\left(1-r^2\right) \\
&= \frac{64}3 \left(1 - \left(1- \cos^2\theta\right)^{3/2}\right) \\
&= \frac{64}3 \left(1 - \left(\sin^2\theta\right)^{3/2}\right)
\end{align*}$$
This is not equivalent to $\dfrac{64}3 \left(1-\sin^3\theta\right)$ because
$$\sqrt{x^2} = |x| \neq x \implies \left(\sin^2\theta\right)^{3/2} = \lvert\sin\theta\rvert^3 = \begin{cases}\sin^3\theta & \theta>0 \\ -\sin^3\theta & \theta<0 \end{cases}$$
The correct $\theta$-integrand is even on the given domain, while yours is odd so that upon integrating over the symmetric interval $\left[-\dfrac\pi2,\dfrac\pi2\right]$, the odd part $\sin^3\theta$ contributes nothing.
Substituting $\theta\to-\theta$ in the negative half of the interval produces the same integral as over the positive half, hence the volume is $2\int_0^{\pi/2}\cdots$ :
$$\begin{align*}
\frac{64}3 \int_{-\tfrac\pi2}^0 \left(1 - \lvert\sin\theta\rvert^3\right) \, d\theta &= \frac{64}3 \int_{-\tfrac\pi2}^0 \left(1 + \sin^3\theta\right) \, d\theta \\
& \!\!\!\stackrel{\theta\to-\theta}= \frac{64}3 \int_0^{\tfrac\pi2} \left(1-\sin^3\theta\right) \, d\theta
\end{align*}$$
